# Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO)

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

We are attempting to migrate from one `Visual Studio Online` account to another `Visual Studio Online` account. This is different from an on-premise `TFS` to `Visual Studio Online` migration. Most articles explain a migration using the on-premise to VSO approach, only.

Accounts

- https:\vsoaccount1.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection
- https:\vsoaccount2.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection

For TFS to VSO, we found a solution by using [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2).

We also tried to use the same tool to point to another `Visual Studio Online` account as a source, but it fails stating that we can only point to a TFS instance.

Can this be done via scripting? If so, how? If there is a tool available, that would be great also. This should be a one time migration.

**Update:**

We need code only, including changesets, **no** work items. The project is using TFVC.

Comment: Are you talking about code only, or work items as well? Do you want full history? Are you using git or TFVC for source control?

Comment: The TFS Integration Platform (link in the answer below) is your only real option.

Comment: I will try it out and report back. Our company restricts us from installing software...

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @jDub, Please see the accepted answer. I was, with difficulties, able to use the TFS Integration Platform.

Comment: @Mario Tacke - I'm looking for the same. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Nash, Oleg's accepted answer below is what we used.

Comment: @jDub. Sorry, for my late reply. Removed all the roles and added Project Collection Admin only. This solved my issue. Either add new User and give Project Collection Admin role or follow what I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider using [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The tool appears to be very complex and somewhat experimental, but we were able to transfer Source Code and change sets from the previous repo to the new one. Thank you.

Comment: True on all 3 counts! But then again, full history migrations are almost never a simple project.

Comment: Mario can you please give me some pointers on how you transferred code and change sets from one VSO account to another. I am in the exactly same situation right now. Thank you.

Comment: @SajadDeyargaroo, install TFS Integration Platform, make sure to use alternate credentials, and select the appropriate template for your migration (they come pre-installed).

Comment: I had tried that but it asks for source and target, when i try to enter the VSO details, if doesn't allow the same.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error? We had a firewall issue at work, so I had to do it off network.

Comment: Note! TFS Integration comes with a scary warning: "TFS Integration Platform was designed to work with Team Foundation Server 2012 and earlier. Use of these integration tools with TFS 2013 and 2015 may cause errors. TFS Integration Platform will not be supported past May 31, 2016."

Answer (score 1):

For others that stumble across this thread, I have found this - the [Visual Studio Team Services Sync & Migration Engine](https://github.com/nkdAgility/vsts-sync-migration) an open source project that appears to do TFS-TFS, TFS-VSTS, VSTS-TFS and VSTS-VSTS migration. It is an open source project initiated with the same purpose as the [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), but to address some of the complexities (and the fact that it is now deprecated).

*From the web site:*

Visual Studio Team Services Sync & Migration Engine allows you to bulk edit data in Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). Supports both migration and bulk update scenarios.