# Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO) - not just code

Tags: testing, tfs, migration, azure-devops

similar question to [Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso) - however we're looking for more than just source code migration.  We'd like to take everything, code, work-items including  links, test plans, test results, the whole shebang.

Has anyone done this, is it possible - or even better supported?

Comment: Have you tried any one of the four templates TFS Integration Platform comes with? At least work items are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft partnered with OpsHub to support this scenario. This recommended over using the TFS Integration Tools.

OpsHub provides a free version of their tool which you can find [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2). This tool supports migrating:

- All version control information and history
- All work items and history
- All test cases and test results

If you need more features, like migrating a customized process template you'll need to use the [paid edition](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim).

Comment: According to the developer: "The migration you outline is feasible with OpsHub commercial offering." See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso/25948418#25948418

Answer (score 1):

This does not work.  The OpsHub tool requires a TFS repository as a source, not a VSO repository.  Perhaps the commercial version gives the ability, but this isn't clear from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Our company had the same problem 2 months ago and spent more than 2 months scratching my head and wandering what to do. We had project running with outsourcing company and we decided to have the repository with them. When the project was over we wanted to migrate the project to our own VSO.

I was surprised to find out that moving all your changes history is possible only with EXPENSIVE software. No way to pay 5K to move 2-3 projects. We asked Microsoft support and they said we can only change ownership to entire VSO account or pay. Well played MS!

I started googling and asking people and at the end we found out a small company specializing in such services called [RuseSoft](https://www.rusesoft.com/contact-us/) / www.rusesoft.com. The guys were very helpful and for a few hundred we moved the projects with ALL THE HISTORY! Took them less than 24h from the time we contacted them.

Still wandering why MS does it and OPS Hub is asking for 5K!

Hope that helps!