# Move source code from one TFS account to another with all History

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I have a `TFS` account which I was using only for `Source Control` management. This had one Main Project (root) and multiple sub projects. Below is the hierarchy.

[image]

Now I have created a different `TFS` account (for some company policy reasons) which is going to be used for both Source code control as well as bugs/features requests control. So I have to move all my source code from my original account to this new account **along with all the revisions and history information**. How I can achieve that?

P.S: I achieved the same thing with `SVN` quite easily by using `SVNADMIN dump/load` utilities. Same thing is required here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the info in screenshot(*visualstudio.com*), seems you are using [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) not the on-premises TFS.

Whether you are going to move your project from VSTS account to an on-premises TFS account or another VSTS account. Both of the situation **can't be figured out through a simple command** as well as SVN.

You have to use below two tools to achieve what you want:

- [OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility](http://opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) (*Some advanced feature
  are not free*)
- [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) (*Free, but a little
  complex*)

Some similar question: [Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso) & [Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO) - not just code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170576/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso-not-just-code)