# How do I migrate project with history between VSO (Visual Studio Online) accounts?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso) says that you need to use TFS Integration Platform, which in the past has not been brilliant for me. I'll give it another shot.

Can this be done with OpsHub Migration tool (perhaps the commercial version?)?

If not, perhaps a good feature to add for a future version.

Comment: Mr Price, are you migrating both work item history and source, or just source? And is the code in git or TFVC?

Comment: Was interested in source history only, no work items. I've just manually checked in the source and started from there. The history is still located in my own VSO. So unless there is a way to merge the two now, it will just stay there for reference. It's only two weeks worth of history so not critical, just a nice to have. It's TFS project not GIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there are several tools available including the TFS Integration Platform, TaskTop, and the [OpsHub Integration Platform](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/alm-systems/tfs/visualstudioonline) that will support the ability to setup migrations & synchronizations between Visual Studio Online accounts.

Comment: OpsHub contacted me to say they would help me and their sales people would contact me. Sales people told me it would cost me $75 per user with minimum of 30 users. Bit much for 2 weeks worth of History from one developer.