# Migrate VSO to VSO with history and work items

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using VSO xxx.visualstudio.com. We have to migrate with history to yyy.visualstudio.com. I know there is no direct tool. Looking for good approach or solution.

Unique Difference with, below question:
[Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso)

1. Export Source code with work Items
2. TFS Integration Platform tool is not working.
3. OpsHub company is taking too long to reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Online migration (VSO to VSO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso)

Comment: @gioele : Its not duplicate. Here I want to export Source Code, Work Items, Changeset etc., As of Today there is not tool available in the market. I'm looking for an approach either Manual or automated.

Comment: Does yyy,visualstudio.com exist?

Comment: What issue are you having with TFS Integration Tools.

Comment: We have a commercial version of our free tool [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2]. known as the OpsHub Integration Manager (http://www.opshub.com/main/) which supports VSO to VSO migration/integration. You can reach out to sales@opshub.com for more details.

Comment: @Lukkha Yes, yyy.visualstudio.com are existing instance running with 1 project.

Comment: @opshub-inc has a commercial version of [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2] known as the OpsHub Integration Manager (opshub.com/main) which they say "supports VSO to VSO migration/integration". sales@opshub.com for more details. (I'm not affiliated with them)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TFS Integration Tools to move TFVC code and Work Items from one Team Project to another regardless of TFS/VSO version.

I have done this a number of times and it works pretty well..

Comment: Are you referring to your ADS Migration Tools, found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration)? I'm interested in migrating from an on-prem 2019 XML process model collection to an on-prem 2019 Inheritance process model collection, to include both work items and history. History is especially important.